# Synchronization in MPI

Tags: parallel-processing, synchronization, mpi

I'm am trying to synchronize my program using MPI, I tried the MPI Barrier but some processors execute past that point before waiting for others.

```
bubble(low_bound, (upper_bound - low_bound));
MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

I'm calling a bubble sort function. I want all processors to be done with this section before proceeding to the next part of the code, which is why I use the MPI_Barrier, but it doesn't work, the program sometimes finishes execution before some processors return their result to the bubble sort function.

Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUM_ELEM 64 //number of elements to be sorted
#define MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG 1 //tag for messages sent from master to slaves
#define SLAVE_TO_MASTER_TAG 4 //tag for messages sent from slaves to master
void createList(); //makes the unsorted list
void bubble(int x, int y, double a[]);
void Merge(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
void printList(); //print the content of sorted list
int rank; //process rank
int size; //number of processes
double List[NUM_ELEM]; //Store the elements into the array
double start_time; //hold start time
double end_time; // hold end time
int low_bound;  //starting point of the elememnts sent to a slave processor
int low_bound1; //New lowerbound of second list
int upper_bound; //end point of the number of elements allocated to a slave    processor
int upper_bound1;  //New upperbound of second list
int portion; //portion of the total number of elements sent to a slave processor
MPI_Status status; // store status of a MPI_Recv
MPI_Request request; //capture request of a MPI_Isend
int list1[NUM_ELEM];
int list2[NUM_ELEM];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv); //initialize MPI operations
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank); //get the rank
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size); //get number of processes

    int i,j;

if(rank == 0)
{
    start_time = MPI_Wtime();

    createList();
    printList();

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
            portion = (NUM_ELEM/size);
            low_bound = i * portion;
 if(((i+1) == size) && ((NUM_ELEM % size) != 0))
                    upper_bound = NUM_ELEM;
            else
                    upper_bound = low_bound + portion;

            //Send the lowe_bound, then upper_bound and then portion
            MPI_Isend(&low_bound,1,MPI_INT,i, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
            MPI_Isend(&upper_bound,1,MPI_INT,i, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
            MPI_Isend(&List[low_bound],(upper_bound - low_bound),MPI_DOUBLE,i, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG+2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);
    }
}


    //Receiving the sent information from the Master process
    MPI_Recv(&low_bound,1,MPI_INT,0, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    MPI_Recv(&upper_bound,1,MPI_INT,0, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG+1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    MPI_Recv(&List[low_bound],(upper_bound - low_bound),MPI_DOUBLE,0, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG+2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);


    bubble(low_bound, (upper_bound - low_bound), List);

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
            if(rank == i)
                    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    i = 1;
    int z;

    while(i != size)
    {
            for(j = i; j < size; j += (i*2))
            {
                    z = j-i;
                    if(rank == j)
                    {
                            MPI_Send(&low_bound,1,MPI_INT,(j-i), MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG+3, MPI_COMM_WORLD /*&request*/);
                            MPI_Send(&upper_bound,1,MPI_INT,(j-i), MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG+4, MPI_COMM_WORLD /*&request*/);
                            MPI_Send(&List[low_bound],(upper_bound - low_bound),MPI_DOUBLE,(j-i), MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG+5, MPI_COMM_WORLD /*&request*/);
                    }

                    if(rank == z)
                    {
                            MPI_Recv(&low_bound1,1,MPI_INT,j, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG+3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                            MPI_Recv(&upper_bound1,1,MPI_INT,j, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG+4, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                            MPI_Recv(&List[low_bound1],(upper_bound1 - low_bound1),MPI_DOUBLE,j, MASTER_TO_SLAVE_TAG+5, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

                //      Merge(low_bound, (upper_bound - low_bound), low_bound1, (upper_bound1 - low_bound1));
                    }
            }

            MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            i = i * 2;
    }

    end_time = MPI_Wtime();

    if(rank == 0)
    {
            printList();

            printf("\nRunning Time = %f\n\n", end_time - start_time);
    }

 MPI_Finalize(); //finalize MPI operations
 return 0;

 }
```

Comment: Posting [more of] your code will help. But, "finishes execution before some  processors return their result to the bubble sort function"? How are they posting the results? Is _every_ process doing the `MPI_Barrier` call?

Comment: I'll post more of the code now, but yh i believe all of the processes have the mpi_barrier call

Comment: They could be in a wrong [or ineffective] place. Also, what you use to send data back [presumably to the root] node may not be functioning as you believe. And, there are some other calls that may be more suitable than `MPI_Barrier` to synchronize results, depending on the totality of your application.

Comment: This is better, but there's still no code that shows the clients sending results to master

Comment: I'll post the full code

Comment: I don't understand why `MPI_Barrier` is called in a `for` loop.  The loop seems useless.

Comment: We're still missing `bubble`, `printList`, `createList`. But, I already see some problems. I'd like to be able to build and run before I post an answer

Comment: What is the `mpirun` command [with options] you are using?

Comment: yh I know the loop is redundant, I just got desperate and was testing out something

Comment: Create list uses a random number generator to generate some numbers within a range of 1000. Print List just as the name says prints the elements in the list, a single for loop outputing each element. Using MPICC

Comment: When posting code please consider a [mcve].

Comment: When using `MPI_Isend`, you must not touch the send buffer before you know from `MPI_Wait` or `MPI_Test` that the request has locally been completed.